# When Updating form check if radio button value in not changed using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form which have group of different multiple radio button for Y/N (1/2). After submitting form everything is working fine.I don't want to update form, I want to keep old records so I insert new record for radio button.
So the problem is when I edit a form and changing values for some fields all the radio button which are not changed or edited is also submitted and a new record is inserted every time even if I edit single field.
Is there any way to check if radio button is not changed and insert 0 if not changed?

**Form Image :**

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ugW.png)

```
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"  style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
  <input type="radio" class="form-radio mud_flap" <?php echo ($row['mud_flap']==1)? 'checked':'' ?> value="1" name="mud_flap"  autofocus /> Yes
  <input type="radio" class="form-radio" <?php echo ($row['mud_flap']==2)? 'checked':'' ?> value="2"  name="mud_flap"  /> No
</div>
```

-----On Submit--------

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$data_child=array(
'check_id'=>$check_id,
'mud_flap'=>$_POST['mud_flap'],
'mud_flap_remark'=>$_POST['mud_flap_remark']);
$where_user =  array('check_id'=>$check_id);
$update = $db->update('vehicle_checklist_master',$data,$where_user)->affectedRows();
$insert = $db->insert('vehicle_checklist_child',$data_child,$where_user);
$_SESSION["updatemsg"]='Checklist Successfully Updated';
header("Location:vehicle_checklist.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: If new record is inserted in edit record then there is a problem in your code in update record case. Post your code

Comment: kindly share your php code through you are going to update your data.

Comment: I have added on update code